# URL rewriting with 3 variables

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

I want to do URL rewriting of my webpage.  There are 2 sorts of links possible on the same page as follows:

Pagination:
http://www.xxxxx.com/dictionnaire.php?page=4
That I want to look like this:
http://www.xxxxx.com/dictionnaire/p4

Word:
http://www.xxxxx.com/dictionnaire.php?idW=675&word=Resto-basket
That I want to look like this:
http://www.xxxxx.com/dictionnaire/675/Resto-basket

In the .htaccess, I have the following:

```
RewriteRule    ^dictionnaire/p([0-9]+)?$    dictionaire.php?page=$1    [NC,L]    
RewriteRule    ^dictionnaire/([0-9]+)/([a-z])?$    dictionaire.php?idW=$1&word=$2   [NC,L]
```

QUESTIONS:

1. Is this the best google friendly way of doing this? (mostly for the word link, or is there better?)
2. Can you have 2 rewrite rules for one link? Like above?
3. Is there an error in my code, is so, please help.
4. When I created this code, my CSs and images weren't appearing.  Can you help me fix it?

I know it's a long question, but I thought it would be easier that way.

Thank for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Is this the best google friendly way of doing this? (mostly for the word link, or is there better?)** Well, you could put page4 in the Pagination part, either won't really affect it much.  For the Word page, why do you have it find words by IDs instead of the actual word?  the word=(WORD) doesn't really seem to do anything at all.  Perhaps remove ID entirely and have it search by word so that it could be dictionnaire/word/(WORD) instead.
2. **Can you have 2 rewrite rules for one link? Like above?** Yes, it is completely possible to have more than 2 rewrite rules (Think many forums that do this)
3. **Is there an error in my code, is so, please help.** I haven't looked hard, but it doesn't appear to be any errors.
4. **When I created this code, my CSs and images weren't appearing. Can you help me fix it?** The problem here is it is searching /dictionnaire/p4/css.file.css for your css file.  It isn't looking in your root directory like I suppose you want.  Put the direct root to your CSS file starting with a / at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

1. This should be "Google friendly".
2. Yes, rewrite rules are applied in order; as soon as one matches and replaces the URL, it's unlikely any further ones will match (since they'll be working on the replaced URL of the previous one).
3. Looks OK to me. You could make it into one rule though, if you allowed the destination URLs to be a little different (to both use page= rather than idW= on the second one).
4. That's because the browser will ask for resources relative to the non-rewritten URL (it of course doesn't know about what's going on behind the scenes). You'll have to use absolute URLs for your images and CSS (or alternatively, use ../ in the URLs, or add more rewrite rules for your resources to make them work).

Hope that helps.

EDIT: Sorry, because you have that [L] at the end of your rules, it will stop trying to match any more rules once it matches one. This won't have any practical effect in this case.